# Display result on a single table

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I've got multiple values within a tree query.. I wish to get all the 3 values of the array and display the results in a table.. unfortunately I'm having only records for the 3rd one, I've even echo the table within the second array, but display nothing.. is there any way to do it?

```
 $sql = mysql_query("select userid from dept_user where lead_id=61");

 while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

  // $user = $res['userid'];
    $a = $res['userid'];

    if ($a !== 0){
      echo "1st: " . $a;
      echo "<br/>";
      $s = mysql_query("select userid from dept_user where lead_id=$a");

      while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $q = $res['userid'];
        echo "<br/>";

        if($q !==0) {
          echo  "Second: " . $q;
          echo "<br/>";
          $f = mysql_query("select userid from dept_user where lead_id=$q");

          while($res = mysql_fetch_array($f)) {
            $u = $res['userid'];
            $n = mysql_query("Select user.firstname, user.lastname, department.dept_name, job_title.title, role.rolename, user.userid From user Inner Join  dept_user On user.userid = dept_user.userid Inner Join  department On department.dept_id = dept_user.dept_id Inner Join  job_title On job_title.title_id = user.titleid Inner Join  role On role.roleid = user.roleid Where user.userid = $u "); 
            echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

<th>id</th>
<th>first name</th>
<th>last name</th>
<th>dept name</th>
<th>title</th>
<th>rolename</th>
</tr>";

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($n)) {

              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['userid'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['dept_name'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
              echo "<td>"  . $row['rolename'] . "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
            }

          echo "</table>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rename variable in the second and third cycle from $res to $res1 and $res2

Comment: ok thx noted.. can i use the same variable everywhere when sedifning the array. $a = $res1['userid'];, $a = $res2['userid'];
, $a = $res['userid'];